# Adding start separate page in django app

Tags: python, django, templates, authentication

I want to add a separate homepage in my Django app.
If a user is logged in to show him all the content.
If the user is not logged in to show him the starting page and a link to login.

The solution is based on the code below does not always pass the exam.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated  %}

//Something

{% else %}

//Something

{% endif %}
```

My view:

```
class Start(TemplateView):
    template_name = "dashboard/start.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`get_template_names()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) method of the view and render different templates for anonymous and logged users:

```
class Start(TemplateView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return ['dashboard/dashboard.html']
        return ['dashboard/start.html']
```